# Sending automated alerts through a XMPP server via command line? (WINDOWS)

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, xmpp, openfire

I've spent hours trying to figure out the answer to this and just continue to come up empty handed. I've setup a XMPP server through OpenFire that is fully functional. My goal with creating the server was placing an alert system for when an event is completed on my server. For example when one of my renders is finished rendering (takes hours, sometimes days), it has the option of running a command when it's finished. This command would then run a .bat file telling a theoretical program to send a message via the broadcast plugin in OpenFire to all parties involved in the render. So it needs to be able to receive parameters such as %N for name of the render and %L for the label of it.

I've located two programs that do exactly what I'm looking to do but one does not work and from the sounds of the comments may have never worked and the second one is seemingly LINUX only. The render server is Windows as is the OpenFire server so naturally it would not work. Here are the links though so you can get an idea.

http://thwack.solarwinds.com/media/40/orion-npm-content/general/136769/xmpp-command-line-client/

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/sendxmpp.1.html

Basically the command I want to push is identical to that of the first link.

**xmppalert.exe -m "%N is complete." %L@broadcast.myserver**

This would broadcast to everyone in the labels Group that the named render is complete.

If anyone has any idea how to get either of the above links working, know of another way or simply have a better idea on how to accomplish what I'm trying to do please let me know. This is something that has been eating at me for 2 days now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at PoshXMPP which allows you to use XMPP from the Powershell.
http://poshxmpp.codeplex.com/

Alex

Comment: Checking this out. Thank you.